# Pattern for "arbitrary data storage" - tiled map

Tags: java, design-patterns, storage

I'm building a tiled map system.

There's a **TileModel**, shared among all tiles of the type; it handles rendering, animation, tile states etc.

Then there's **TileData**, which represents concrete tile in the tiled map, holds a pointer to it's model, and any save-able data (tiles can contain dropped items, trap properties, hidden doors, lockable doors etc). *Model* handles the saving.

```
           TileModel
    +---------------------+                  TileData
    | Rendering code      |        +-------------------------+
    | Animation code      |        | Data for concrete tile  |
    | Tile state handling |<-------| Pointer to Model        |
    | Saving / Loading    |        +-------------------------+
    +---------------------+
```

Now comes the thing I'm unsure about - I want to allow models to store arbitrary data in the tile.

Some options:

- `Object` field in `TileData` into which `TileModel` can put it's data storage (of any type)
- `int[]`, `boolean[]` etc arrays in `TileData`, and force `TileModel` to use only those.
- `Map<String,Object>` in `TileData` for this extra data. I think that'd be wasteful.

What pattern is the most efficient (fastest, cleanest, least memory expensive)?

Answer (score 0):

Make a `TileModelData` interface and create a set of tile model classes that implement `TileModelData` and contain members for the data specific to that tile model.

```
interface TileModelData {
    TileModel getModel();
}

class TileData {
    ...
    TileModelData modelData;
}

class OceanTileData implements TileModelData {
    static TileModel model = TileModel.Ocean;
    TileModel getModel() { return model; } 
    int oceanDepth;
}

class ForestTileData implements TileModelData {
    ...
    int treeDensity;
}
```

Comment: Hm.. I'm not sure you understood the problem the way I meant.. Model is a unique implementation of the tile logic / parameters / rendering, and Tile is merely a data holder.

Comment: What would be some examples of tile models and data?

Comment: It's hard to explain in short comment.. TileData is a piece of a huge array representing the world. Each tile contains current data, such as dropped items, chest contents, door unlock states. Then Models are one-for-all-of-type, kinda singletons to which tiles have reference. It's kinda logic-data separation pattern. Anyway I have some basic impl now done, so let's let it be. It's not super pretty, but seems to work.